# Fetching property value from child class and add it to dest object c#

Tags: c#, propertyinfo

I have a static method that has two parameters, one that is source object that contains all info and a destination object that I want to transfer all values to.

The problem is that the class has nested classes and I don't know how to add it to the `dest` object.

I appreciate all help that I can get.

To call the method looks like this:

```
Automapper(annonsDto, new Annons(){ 
            Model = new Model()
                 {Company = new Company()}, 
                         User = new Users()});

private static Object Automapper(Object source, Object dest)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] sourcePropertyInfos = source.GetType().GetProperties();
        Array.Sort(sourcePropertyInfos, delegate(PropertyInfo propertyInfo1, PropertyInfo propertyInfo2)
        {
            return propertyInfo1.Name.CompareTo(propertyInfo2.Name);
        });

        foreach (PropertyInfo sourcePropertyInfo in sourcePropertyInfos)
        {
            if (sourcePropertyInfo.PropertyType.IsClass)
            {
                if (sourcePropertyInfo.PropertyType.FullName.ToLower().Contains("xXxXx"))
                {
                    var nestedClass = sourcePropertyInfo.GetValue(source, null);
                    Automapper(nestedClass, dest);
                    continue;
                }
            }

            dest = TransferPropValue(sourcePropertyInfo.Name, source, dest);
        }

        return dest;
    }

    private static Object TransferPropValue(String targetName, Object sourceObj, Object destObj)
    {
        if (sourceObj == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        Type destType = destObj.GetType();
        PropertyInfo destInfo = destType.GetProperty(targetName);

        Type sourceType = sourceObj.GetType();
        PropertyInfo sourceInfo = sourceType.GetProperty(targetName);
        if (sourceInfo == null) { return null; }

        try
        {
            var sourceValue = sourceInfo.GetValue(sourceObj, null);
            destInfo.SetValue(destObj, sourceValue, null);
        }
        catch (Exception) { }

        return destObj;
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to clone them? If your objects are serializable and of the same type - I'd serialize and deserialize them. If they are of different types - potentially, you may have more problems than you solve.

Comment: Could you be more specific to what the problem is?

Comment: Sourcde object is a Model Object and the dest object is a Domain Object, however they look the same.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the replay

Sourcde object is a Model Object and the dest object is a Domain Object, however they look the same.

I want to mapp over the source object to te dest object, everything is working fine but when it comse to the nested class I dont know how to add it to the dest object.

Comment: The domain object look like this
public class Annons
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual String ModellForetagsNamn { get; set; }
        public virtual String ModellNamn { get; set; }
        public virtual int Aktiv { get; set; }
        public virtual int Privat { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime Skapad { get; set; }
        public virtual Users User { get; set; }
        public virtual Model Model { get; set; }
    }

Comment: And the Model object look like this
public class AnnonsDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public String ModellForetagsNamn { get; set; }
        public String ModellNamn { get; set; }
        public int Aktiv { get; set; }
        public int Privat { get; set; }
        public DateTime Skapad { get; set; }
        public virtual UserDto User { get; set; }
        public virtual ModelDto ModelDto { get; set; }
    }